# Why doesn't my nav have the same width as my container in CSS when used position: fixed?

Tags: html, css, css-position, nav

If I add `position: fixed` to the CSS code of `nav` the navbar doesn't have the same width as the container, can someone help me?

My HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="guestbook.html">Guestbook</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
            <li id="login" ><a href="logn.html">Login</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </nav>

<p>Example text</p>
<p>Example text</p>
<p>Example text</p>
<p>Example text</p>
<p>Example text</p>
<p>Example text</p>
<p>Example text</p>
<p>Example text</p>
</div>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url('img/background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

#container {
    background-color:#D3D3D3;
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: grey;
}

li {
    float:left;
}

#login {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #A1D490;
}

.active {
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    color: grey;
}
```

If I add this to the CSS the navbar has the width of its content:

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Can someone please help me?
I searched on different websites en nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: `nav { position: fixed; left: 0; right: 0; }`

Answer (score 2):

That's because the default is `width: auto`.

For [Block-level, non-replaced elements in normal flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth),

> The following constraints must hold among the used values of the other
>   properties:
>
> ```
> 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block
> ```
>
> If there is exactly one value specified as 'auto', its used value
>   follows from the equality.
>
> If 'width' is set to 'auto', any other 'auto' values become '0' and
>   'width' follows from the resulting equality.

However, when you take it out of flow with `position: fixed`, then [Absolutely positioned, non-replaced elements applies](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width) instead.

> If all three of 'left', 'width', and 'right' are 'auto': First set any
>   'auto' values for 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' to 0. Then, if the
>   'direction' property of the element establishing the static-position
>   containing block is 'ltr' set 'left' to the static position
>
> 'width' and 'right' are 'auto' and 'left' is not 'auto', then the
>   width is shrink-to-fit .

You can try to set another width, e.g. `width: 100%`. But note the percentage will be resolved according to the [containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details) which, for fixed elements, is usually the viewport.

Consider adding `position: relative` to the parent and using `position: absolute` instead of `fixed` in your element so that `width: 100%` makes it be as wide as the parent.

Comment: Thanks, now is the width of the navigation the same as the container.
But how can I make the position of the nav fixed? So if I scroll through the page tha nav stays on top of the screen.

Comment: Use `position: sticky` instead

Comment: Thanks, now the whitspace is gone that was another problem haha, but if I scroll to the bottom then I can't see the navigation bar, how can I fix that? position: fixed doesn't work, it makes the size of the nav smaller (just the width of the content)

Answer (score 0):

When it is set to fixed it is taken out of the document flow. It's parents width doesn't apply to it.

Just add CSS to set the width of the nav bar to be the same as the container. So in this case, set it to 70%.